# how to fix coredns service not found after initializing pod network

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, coredns

I started with Kubernetes tutorial and after intializeing the pod network

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml
```

I discovered that coredns is pending but rest of the services were running.

```
# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-gzn5l             0/1     Pending   0          19m
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-k2h5m             0/1     Pending   0          19m
```

the I tried to look at the logs:

```
# kubectl logs coredns-74ff55c5b-gzn5l
Error from server (NotFound): pods "coredns-74ff55c5b-gzn5l" not found
# kubectl logs coredns-74ff55c5b-k2h5m
Error from server (NotFound): pods "coredns-74ff55c5b-k2h5m" not found
```

Comment: can you give me the output of `kubectl -n kube-system describe pod coredns-74ff55c5b-gzn5l`? And the log doesn't work because the pod hasn't been created yet, the describe subcommand usually tells you what happens

Comment: How can i create pod and add to kube-system namespace afterwards then?

Comment: What? You can create pod in `kube-system` namespace, the problem now is the scheduling problem, either the pod doesn't have proper tolerations to run on your available nodes or if I remember correctly something with CNI also can cause this state, like I said before, run the `kubectl -n kube-system describe pod coredns-74ff55c5b-gzn5l` it will tell you what happens

Comment: Also from your pod output, seems like you haven't install your calico

Comment: Please include in your question the Kubernetes tutorial site that you used (if it's possible) and/or exact steps you've followed to get to this point. By that you will easier the debugging process as this issue could be located in the Kubernetes provisioning process.